# About mirroring a piece of text

Tags: graphics, rotating, text-decorations, text-manipulation

I would like to produce a mirrored version of the Lorem ipsum text. How can I do this? If I use `\reflectbox` or `\scalebox`, everything ends up in a single line of text. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, mathrsfs, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\reflectbox{
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\\
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\reflectbox{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is probably not going to work across several pages, though. But to that end, you could use [pdfpages](/questions/tagged/pdfpages) to embed (and `reflect`) entire pdf documents.